# Get last 2 or 3 elements from path regex

Tags: javascript, regex

So i currently have a path and i am trying to fetch the last 3;

**Test**:

```
/testing/path/here/src/handlebar/sample/colors.txt
/testing/path/here/src/handlebar/testing/another/colors.txt
```

**Regex**:

```
\/([^/]+\/[^/]+\/[^/]+)\.[^.]+$
```

**Result**:

```
handlebar/sample/colors
testing/another/colors
```

**What i want it to do**:

```
sample/colors
testing/another/colors
```

If there are 2 directories and then the item, it should utilise the 3 and if it contains the word **handlebar**, it should only be two.

Comment: Do you need like this "sample/colors.txt" output or ""sample/colors" this..Please confirm once..Thanks.

Comment: without the extension

Comment: You can't use something simple with capturing like [`handlebar/([^.]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/on9Li2/1) for extraction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just create a group for everything behind `handlebar/` like this:

with a named capturing group (subPath group contains wanted value):

```
/handlebar\/(?<subPath>\S*)\.\S+$/gm
```

without naming (first group contains wanted value):

```
/handlebar\/(\S*)\.\S+$/gm
```

Explanation: This regex matches everything ending with 'handlebar/(...any non white-space chacters 0 to infinite times).(any white-space character 1-inifite times)'. With flags globally and multiline, if you want to check multiple paths within one string separated with a line break e.g.

As you tagged the question with the tag `javascript`, here is some example code, how to retrieve the value of the regex group

```
function getSubPath(fullPath = '') {
  const regex = /handlebar\/(?<subPath>\S*)\.\S+$/gm
  const match = regex.exec(fullPath)
  if (match) {
    return match.groups.subPath
  }
  return fullPath // regex.exec did not deliver match
}

getSubPath('/testing/path/here/src/handlebar/sample/colors.txt')
// returns 'sample/colors'

getSubPath('/testing/path/here/src/handlebar/testing/another/colors.txt')
// returns 'testing/another/colors'
```

without the named group, just read / return match.groups[1] for first capturing group; index 0 is for the full match (which would include the '/handlebars' and the file extension)

Answer (score 3):

I hope you'll get like this.

This is the dynamic tomorrow you can pass as per your required parameters and get result..

```html
<script>
  var res = "/testing/path/here/src/handlebar/sample/colors.txt";
  var res1 = "/testing/path/here/src/handlebar/testing/another/colors.txt";;

  Result = (val, text) => {
    var r = val.split(text + '/')[1];
    return r.substr(0, r.lastIndexOf('.'));
  }
  console.log(Result(res, "handlebar"));
  console.log(Result(res1, "handlebar"));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A javascript solution without regex would look like this:

```
const getTokenizedPath = path => {
  const pathArray = path.split('/');
  // last element of array looks like "colors.txt" - split by dot and read the first value, removing the extension
  pathArray[pathArray.length-1] = pathArray[pathArray.length-1].split('.')[0];

  // Remove all elements before the 'handlebar' token and join the remaining values together by '/'.
  return pathArray.slice(pathArr2.indexOf('handlebar')+1).join('/');
}
```

```
getTokenizedPath('/testing/path/here/src/handlebar/sample/colors.txt');
--- sample/colors.txt

getTokenizedPath('/testing/path/here/src/handlebar/testing/another/colors.txt');
--- testing/another/colors
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess,

```
(?!.*handlebar)/([^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+)\.[^.]+$|/([^/]+/[^/]+)\.[^.]+$
```

might work OK.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/aREnX1/1)

and if lookarounds would be supported,

```
(?!.*handlebar)(?<=/)[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+(?=\.[^.]+$)|$|(?<=/)([^/]+/[^/]+)(?=\.[^.]+$)
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/9EFXj3/1)

would be an option too.

```js
const regex = /(?!.*handlebar)\/([^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+)\.[^.]+$|\/([^\/]+\/[^\/]+)\.[^.]+$/gm;
const str = `/testing/path/here/src/handlebar/sample/colors.txt
/testing/path/here/src/handlebar/testing/another/colors.txt`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aREnX1/1). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/aREnX1/1debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---